# I continually get a "Bus Error" while this is code is being executed?

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher, bus-error

The purpose of this code is to take a file that has been passed into the program and generate the letter frequency of each letter in the file. In above code, I remove punctuation and convert to lowercase letters.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileContent = "qr rqh zrxog kdyh eholhyhg lq wkh odvw bhduv ri wkh qlqhwhhqwk fhqwxub wkdw wklv";

    int count[26] =  { 0 }; // an array the size of the alphabet.

    for(int f = 0; f < fileContent.length(); f++) // run til the file end.
    {
            if(fileContent[f] == 32) // to take care of the spaces.
            {
                    f++; // also tried "continue;" and yeild different and also incorrect results.
            }

            if(fileContent[f] >= 48 && fileContent[f] <= 57) //take care of numbers.
            {
                    f++; // tried "continue;"
            }

            count[fileContent[f]]++;

    }

    for(int p = 0; p < 26; p++)
    {
            cout << char(p + 97) << ": " << count[p]  << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get some accurate frequencies, and some horribly incorrect ones (seems like every other result is wrong, yet after a few letters it trails off into astronomically large numbers). Any way to do this better? what is wrong with this code? As per request I have added some more of the code (including  a string with a random 100 in it) as it was apparently not clear enough)

For more context, this program is for a Ceasar shift decoder I'm working on. I am in basic c++ and would greatly appreciate any advise from you more experienced devs. thank you!

Comment: *what is wrong with this code?* -- Advice -- One of the things you have to learn, and is part and parcel in learning how to write programs, is to debug your own programs.  It isn't an anomaly that a program you, me, or user0042 would write could contain mistakes.  The first thing to do is to debug your own code.  One thing that you don't want to be is to act like an "end-user" when your code doesn't work, and call StackOverflow for "customer support".  That gets old very fast, and can get you downvotes.

Comment: You mean you get an error running your program don't you? Compiling is the process of converting the source code to an executable you can run.

Comment: I am a beginner, I am aware of what debugging is and yes I did attempt to debug my code. If there is an error, and my "expertise" is not keen enough to spot it am I supposed to wallow in self-pity for hours? This community is extremely toxic toward new users because of many reasons, one of which is because of an utter lack of compassion for beginners. I adhered to the guidelines he requested. my code that I posted was concise and cut down. I had spent about an hour and a half trying different thing to solve this issue it is not an anomaly that I missed a small error. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: thank you, @Retired Ninja, for that clarification. I'll edit that now!

Comment: @hammonak If you had used some simple print functions to see things in a more granular way, you would have seen the issue pointed out by the answer.  It is that simple to find bugs in simple code.  When your code becomes larger, then you will need to learn to use the debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie A debugger is also a good idea, especially for small programs like this. Depending on platform, the standard debugger might not be easy-to-use, though.

Comment: When I learn how to use a debugger I will surely do that, that thank you. But as I said, I am a beginner only half a semester into a C++ intro course. These simple solutions are not a blatantly obvious to me as they are to you. Not a difficult concept to understand that some people are less skilled than yourself in a particular area. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @hammonak -- It doesn't take a lot of skill to say "hmm. I'm getting a bigger number.  Let me  print out what that line of code is doing.  Aha, it is too large, but what to make it so that it is in range?  Let me take this to SO and share my findings and see what they say".  That little exchange with yourself is all that you needed.  There was no need to use a debugger -- the debugger is `cout` or `printf` and seeing what parts of your code is actually doing.

Comment: @hammonak I think that a debugger should really be one of the first things covered in a beginner course, but I can't set your curriculum. You do, however, know how to do print statements; Paul's suggestion was to just add statements like `cout << "Adding one to count of" << fileContent[f] << endl;` before the increment line and `cout << "Count is now " << count[fileContent[f]] << endl;` after it. This would have let you see that your counts had garbage values and let you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Daniel H, Yes this is clear to me now. I still stand by my statements though. As I am just beginning, these checks are not as intuitive to me. If a user would have initially suggested this instead of being rude and patronizing, I would've definitely attempted this. If you direct yourself to the answer section, that user explained to be the issue I was having with detail. Which seems to be much more efficient and polite than criticising a student for a small mistake.

Comment: @hammonak I understand what you mean about this site being toxic to beginners. I was clarifying Paul's point so that next time, you do think of that solution.

Comment: Yes and if one day I am on this website and stumble upon a beginner with this same issue I will make sure to inform them because sharing knowledge is the best way to secure a brighter and more technologically advanced future. Being rude achieves nothing but temporarily reducing the existential pain that that rude person is enduring, by knowing that their comment has caused another individual to experience frustration. @Daniel H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your program, this statement:

```
count[fileContent[f]]++;
```

should be:

```
count[fileContent[f]-97]++; //Assuming that all alphabets are in lowercase
```

If you do not do `-97`, it is trying to increase the value at index `fileContent[f]` of `count` array, which may be beyond the limit of `count` array.

Also, make sure to `continue` in both the `if` blocks and you don't need to do `f++` explicitly in both the `if` blocks as in the `for` loop you are already doing `f++`.

Comment: thank you! I appreciate the effort you put into answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things the difficult way: using C-style arrays, magic numbers in your code, and risking buffer overflows everywhere.

Compare your code to this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileContent = "qr rqh zrxog kdyh eholhyhg lq wkh odvw bhduv ri wkh qlqhwhhqwk fhqwxub wkdw wklv";
    map<char, int> counts;

    for (char ch : fileContent)
        ++counts[ch];

    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch)
        cout << ch << ": " << counts[ch] << '\n';
}
```

Or to print all the map contents (if you do not want to print 0 for letters that did not occur) you can use:

```
for (auto& item : counts) 
    cout << item.first << ": " << item.second << '\n';
```

Exercise for the reader to add in the code to exclude the spaces and numbers. Hint: look up the [cctype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) header.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will look into this, although I'm not entirely familiar with some of the things you used ( such as "<map>" and "auto" )

Comment: @hammonak The `<map>` header contain the type `std::map`, which lets you use one thing (the key) to look up another thing (the value). For example, a dictionary is a map from words to definitions, and a phone book is a map from names to telephone numbers. The `auto` keyword tells the compiler "You know what type this should be; don't make me spell out the entire thing"; it's useful in a lot of ways, but can sometimes get in the way of learning. In this case, it stands for `pair<char, int>`.

Comment: Thank you for the well put together informative comment @Daniel H